# Finding the greatest prime factor of an integer in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a simple program to find the greatest prime factor of an integer in JavaScript. The code I have written to do this follows:

```js
let ans;

function factor(target, half) {
    for (let i = 2; i < half; i++) {
        if (target % i == 0) {
            ans = target / i;
            factor(ans, ans / 2);
        }
    }
}

factor(30, 15);
console.log(ans);
```

Now whether or not this code is an efficient solution to the problem or if it even works at all is beyond my issue with it: When I follow breakpoints set at each line of the `factor` function, I see that right after `i = 2`, `target = 5`, `half = 2.5`, and `ans = 5`, the value of target and half jump back up to `15` and `7.5` respectively. However, I do not see where in my code the values are told to change.

Comment: You're calling the function recursively. I'm pretty sure you're looking at different instances of the function call.

Comment: @Guy Incognito Thank you for the response but I am confused as to why the function is called recursively with the values _15_ for target and _7.5_ for half after being called recursively with the values _5_ for target and _2.5_ for half.

Comment: You didn't tell where the breakpoints are, but again pretty sure that you're seeing the values when  you come back to the previous function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the function recursively, and *each call* to the function gets its own `target`, `half`, and `i` variables. In the first call to `factor`, `target` is `30` and `half` is `15`. Then you call it again with the arguments `15` and `7.5`; that *inner* call to `factor` gets its own `target` (`15`) and `half` (`7.5`), but the *outer* call still has its copies (`30`) and (`15`). This continues when you call `factor` again recursively, creating a third set, etc. When you step out of the innermost call, its variables disappear and you see the ones that are for the call that called it.

It may be clearer with a simpler example:

```js
function countdown(value, indent) {
    var twice = value * 2;
    console.log(indent + "[before] value = " + value + ", twice = " + twice);
    if (value > 0) {
        countdown(value - 1, indent + "  ");
    }
    console.log(indent + "[after]  value = " + value + ", twice = " + twice);
}
countdown(3, "");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

The output of that is:

```
[before] value = 3, twice = 6
  [before] value = 2, twice = 4
    [before] value = 1, twice = 2
      [before] value = 0, twice = 0
      [after]  value = 0, twice = 0
    [after]  value = 1, twice = 2
  [after]  value = 2, twice = 4
[after]  value = 3, twice = 6
```

As you can see, the values for `value` and `twice` in the outer call aren't changed by making the inner call. Each call gets its own set of variables.